# Unable to install TestNG in Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Tags: eclipse, selenium

I had tried to install TestNG manually and from the Market place, and I am able to see it installed under installation details, but when going to select New > Other > Select wizard and filtered by TestNG it only display JUnit even though TestNG has been installed, and I had also tried to uninstall and reinstall again and same issue.

Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

Comment: Try adding it as a library through the build path.  You can add both JUnit and TestNG that way.

Comment: I had also tried adding it by the build path and same issue, I am not sure if it is a defect on the IDE version. But I also install the IDE and reinstall and the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

The error I was seeing while trying to add TestNG through the market place was that TestNG is not compatible with version of eclipse.

So I backed down to the recommended Photon to begin using TestNG on a new system.